# How can I clear timeout for an asynchronous function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, timeout

Let me be very clear so as to avoid confusion.
I have a sleep function (below) which timeouts for as many millisecond as I specify.

```
function sleep(ms) 
{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Now in another function beginTest() I called sleep for some millisecond let say 5000 ms.

```
async function beginTest()
{
    await sleep(5000);
}
```

I have a separate function which gets executed when a button is clicked. I want the function to clear the timeout whenever the button is clicked before completion of 5000 ms. I understand that after 5000 ms clicking the button should not affect anything as the promise has already been resolved.

```
document.getElementById("reactTimeClick").onmousedown = function()
{
    cleartimeOut(); // Clear timeout of above function
}
```

Comment: Did you try named timeouts?

Comment: Do you mean globally storing the timeout object and clearing it later using cleartimeOut(obj)?

Comment: Yes.........................

Comment: Yes I tried, it wasn't of much help but I just searched for "named" function timeout 
 where simply the function is invoked after timeout and it worked like charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to do as you propose with a "cancellation token" via which the "sleep timeout" can be cancelled:

```
// don't do this
function sleep(ms, cancellationToken) {
    return new Promise(resolve => function() {
        let timeoutRef = setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        cancellationToken.cancel = function() {
            clearTimout(timeoutRef);
        };
    });
}
```

However that will not, in itself, cause the sleep promise to depart from its `pending` state and the promise chain (or awaiting statements) stemming from `sleep()` will not be informed of the cancellation. Progress will hang.

This shortcoming can be overcome, again with a cancellation token, but this time one that allows the `sleep()` promise to be rejected, as follows ...

```
// do this
function sleep(ms, cancellationToken) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => function() {
        cancellationToken.cancel = function() {
            reject(new Error('sleep() cancelled'));
        };
        setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
}
```

... and in the caller, use as follows:

```
async function beginTest() {
    try {
        const token = {};
        const promise = sleep(5000, token);
        $('#cancelButton').on('click', token.cancel); // jQuery example, or similar in POJS
        await promise;
        // ... test code ...
        // ... return whatever;
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        // If button was clicked before the 5000 ms has expired, 
        // and no other error has been thrown, 
        // then the log will show "sleep() cancelled".
        throw error; // rethrow error to keep beginTest's caller informed.
    }
}
```